# Eliminar Array de Localstorage si no esta en la ruta indicada si cambia el path

Tags: angular, typescript

Estimados un gran favor necesito limpiar o eliminar lo que tengo guardado en una llave en el localstorage si se esta fuera o se sale del path indicado debe eliminarse, tengo esta condición y no me funciona su apoyo por favor, es angular Gracias.

```js
if (this.router.url === '/checkout') {
        const urlCheckout = this.router.url;
        if (!urlCheckout){
          localStorage.removeItem('cuponesArr');
          this.actualizarCuponesLocalStorage()
        } else {
          this.leerLocalStorage()
        }
      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No sé muy bien dónde estás realizando esta evaluación, pero si es en un componente de página, no hay manera de que las url obtenidas cambien, ya que siempre va a recibir la url del componente actual.

Por este motivo, te recomiendo que directamente realices la operatoria de lectura en el componente home (o equivalente) y el de eliminación en el checkout.

Para graficar mejor lo dicho, te paso un proyecto sencillo que te preparé:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/local-storage-test1?file=src/app/home/home.component.ts

Avisame si esto es lo que necesitabas.

Un abrazo.

Comment: Hola Juan pablo creo que seria al inverso, en el checkout debe mantenerse, y otro lados debe eliminarse, la evaluación es un componente que apunta ese path, checkout allí debe mantener el localstorage si se sale de esa ruta debe elimarse,

Comment: Disculpame, sí, así es. No di mucha importancia a lo que hace la pantalla en sí. Independientemente de la lógica de negocio, lo que intenté proponer es que las operatorias del localStorage deberían realizarse independientemente por componente.